# URI is not registred error in andriod studio at build/intermediate/res/merged/debug/menu/menu.xml

Tags: android, debugging

I think because of this when I build and luanch an application it is closing immediately. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4X1Gh.png)

Can I anyone tell me why exactly this is crashing?

Comment: can you add the logcat stacktrace of the crash?

Comment: logcat stacktrace is  not captured

Comment: It is hard to tell why your app is crashing without looking at the stacktrace.

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.nurlagun.wfcvit, PID: 27489 java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder cannot be cast to android.view.

Comment: How to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing logcat we cann't know the reason why your application is crashing
Go to Android studio at bottom you will see logcat option, open it then you will see stacktrace it will helps in finding the reason.[image]

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.nurlagun.wfcvit, PID: 27489 java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder cannot be cast to android.view.

Comment: How to reslove this ?

Comment: without having source code i can't find actual reason, post your piece of code.

Comment: delete build folder, and rebuild again, run the application it may work.